# Indexing issues with Xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

For some reason, defined outlets in XCode are not appearing in the right-click menu when I try to associate an object in the view with the outlet. For example:

```
import UIKit

class EditProfileTableViewController: UITableViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var photoImageView: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet var businessName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var businessAddress: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var businessHours: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var businessPhoneNumber: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var businessWebsite: UITextField!
...
```

As seen in the above example, there are many text fields that were defined, but if I try to associate the outlets to the objects in the view, it doesn't even appear in the right click menu here. (The photoImageView outlet was defined about a month ago, but for some reason the new outlets aren't working.)

[image]

In fact, the Identity Inspector shows nothing in the Class dropdown menu:
[image]

I believe there was some type of hiccup syncing files on Dropbox and something was accidentally deleted, and now I'm not quite sure how to fix this. I've tried:

- Cleaning and re-building the project
- Removing the project directories from "~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData" to force Xcode to re-index (and restarted Xcode)

and still nothing. I'd really hate to completely wipe my project and start from scratch, so I'm hoping to be able to get this resolved. I doubt it's anything as far as in the application that's done incorrectly since this worked before, but I'm not 100%.

If I copy my project folder to another location (let's say from DropBox to my Desktop), everything works perfectly fine! Confusing!

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible situation out of my head.

1. Double check that your view controller on storyboard is really connected to your code. Set a break point in `viewDidLoad` function to validate this.
2. If the connection is correct, then the cause of this issue could be that your outlet code is somehow disconnected from the elements on your storyboard. To fix this, do right click on your view controller like your second screen shot. In Outlets section, delete all connections by clicking on the little cross sigh in the middle. Then reconnect by ctr drag the element to your outlets in view controllers.

Comment: Thanks man! I just discovered that copying the project folder to another location (let's say from dropbox to my desktop), everything works perfectly. Any ideas why this would be the case? It's supposed to be the exact same files (literally just copied the whole folder from one place to another)

Comment: @LewlSauce You are saying that copying and pasting project will not affect the connection? This is actually true because your connections are stored in your storyboard file as XML format. I use github for all my project and when I download project, I am copying the project from github server to my local and everything works.

Comment: Yeah I would think that copying the entire project folder from one location to another location shouldn't affect the project at all whatsoever. However, it's definitely doing that for me. Not sure why this works for me on my local system but not if it's being synced/stored on dropbox.

Comment: Anyway, using a source control to store your code is always and way better than dropbox. Good luck on your project :)

Comment: Yeah I'm definitely with you there. Might end up finding another solution (perhaps github) since another person is working on it as well